# Traefik 2.4: redirect http to https based on IP / Header

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

Im using traefik with a global redirect from http to https, using this commands in docker-compose file

```
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true"
```

Which works just fine.

Now, is there a possiblity to make this global redirect rule-based? I want to **redirect** all traffic from **http to https**, **but if a specific header** is presented **or** the request comes from a **specific IP**, the redirect should **not take place**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need to redirect based on source IP. The solution has 3 parts:

1. Rule to match the `X-Real-IP` Header,
2. Set a higher priority and
3. Optionally use middleware to exclude IPs that should not match.

I use YAML format with the file provider. The priority is based on the rule length so you'll want to make it larger to override long rules. The `private-ips` middleware should not be reached and is there mostly for testing.

```
# Private service
[http.routers.example-private]
    priority = 100
    entrypoints = [ "web-secure" ]
    service = "example-private"
    rule = "Host(`example.com`) && (Headers(`X-Real-Ip`, `127.0.0.1`) || Headers(`My-Header`, `some-value`))"
    middlewares = [ "private-ips@file" ]

# Public service
[http.routers.example]
    priority = 10
    entrypoints = [ "web-secure" ]
    service = "example"
    rule = "Host(`example.com`)"
    middlewares = [ "redirect-https@file" ]

# Private IPs
[http.middlewares.private-ips.ipWhiteList]
    sourceRange = [
        "127.0.0.1/32",         # localhost
    ]

# Permanent redirect to HTTPS.
[http.middlewares.redirect-https.redirectScheme]
    scheme = "https"
    permanent = true
```